# Converting String in "Data" Format within Mathematica

Tags: import, data

Hi I have a simple question. Given a random string in the format accepted by the `Import[fileWithString, "Data"]` i.e the file contents being

```
data = "0 0
0.73 400
0.92 600
1.05 800
1.15 1000
1.28 1400
1.42 2000
1.52 3000
1.58 4000
1.6 6000"
```

Is there a way to easily convert this to numerical data using a simple built in function. I can do the following.

```
Export["~/Desktop/t.txt", data]
Import["~/Desktop/t.txt", "Data"]

(* {{0, 0}, {0.73, 400}, {0.92, 600}, {1.05, 800}, {1.15, 1000}, {1.28, 
  1400}, {1.42, 2000}, {1.52, 3000}, {1.58, 4000}, {1.6, 6000}} *)
```

I just want to use the "Data" interpreter outside of the import function and I dont want to have to type something like

```
ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#, " "] & /@ StringSplit[data, "\n"]

(* {{0, 0}, {0.73, 400}, {0.92, 600}, {1.05, 800}, {1.15, 1000}, {1.28, 
  1400}, {1.42, 2000}, {1.52, 3000}, {1.58, 4000}, {1.6, 6000}} *)
```

everytime I want to parse a simple string. It would be nice if I could do something like `ToExpression[data, "Data"]` but that unfortunately wont work.

Comment: `ImportString[ data, "Data"]` ?  or maybe `ImportString[data, "Table"]`

Comment: `ImportString` is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From LouisB in the comments

```
ImportString[data, "Data"]
```